# Making HTTP request with NodeJs Parse Error: Invalid header token

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I'm trying to make a request to this url: https://arfrontend.livemeans.com/contents.jsonp?op=604
In the browser works fine. But when i try to make it on NodeJs i have this error.

```
Uncaught Error Error: Parse Error: Invalid header token
```

This is the code that I'm using.

```
const https = require('https');


var asd = https.request('https://arfrontend.livemeans.com/contents.jsonp?op=604', (r) => {
    debugger;
});

asd.addListener("response", (de) => {
    debugger
})

asd.end()
```

I want to get the Json like on the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving to http module will work.

```
const http = require('http');
const options = {
  hostname: 'arfrontend.livemeans.com',
  path: '/contents.jsonp?op=604',
  method: 'GET'
};

const asd = http.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log('Response status code:', res.statusCode);
  let data = '';

  res.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data += chunk;
  });

  res.on('end', () => {
    console.log('Response data:', data);
  });
});

asd.on('response', (res) => {
  console.log('Response headers:', res.headers);
});

asd.end();
```

Comment: you need to handle the response data to extract and parse the JSON content!

Comment: agreed. but that can be done easily. i was demonstrating how successfully get that response back from server without having Error: Error - Parse Error: Invalid header token

Comment: Anyway I updated the code to extract the data as well.

Comment: That's it Thank You